# I have installed WxWidgets, but PgAdmin cannot see it

Tags: installation, wxwidgets, pgadmin

There was a similar question (here or on some related SE site), but I didn't find so I ask a new question (if you find it, send a link and vote to close this question if they are too similar).

I have finished installing WxWidgets (configure; make; make install), but while installing PgAdmin III 1.16 the make console doesn't recognize WxWidgets as installed. I found that absence of Unicode might be a problem in this case, but I have enabled the Unicode. What else should I do?

I have 32bit Windows XP and WxWidgets 2.9.4. Including PostgreSQL 9.1.3 went OK.

EDIT: I tried another way - through Visual Studio and Visual C++. I don't know if my problem is the same or just similar, but Visual Studio reports this error:

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'wx/wxprec.h': No such file or directory
```

followed by 100 of other errors which seem to be conclusion of this one (mostly undefined types/functions with names beginning with "wx"). I added semicolons to the header (as was suggested [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/313ddfa0-80cb-4abc-8f08-9004e9b15b59) - fourth entry after "all replies"), but it didn't help. I also tried to add "include" and "lib" directories in WxWidgets to include path for every project, but no joy here.

Do anybody know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to point pgAdmin to wxWidgets installation under Windows. Its build instruction should explain how to do it but you must set up the include path (`-I` compiler option) and the libraries path (`-L` linker option) for it to compile and link properly.

Notice that for the include paths you must put the directory containing the `wx/setup.h` file generated during the build by configure first and the directory with all the rest of wx headers later.

Also, it probably goes without saying, but you must use the same compiler to build both wxWidgets and pgAdmin, so if you built wx using configure+make you can't use MSVC for pgAdmin.